# CSS doesn't work on HTTPS pages in Chrome and IE

Tags: css, internet-explorer, google-chrome, https

On my site, Chrome can't load a stylesheet if the page is opened with https.

For instance, on the page test.php I have the following CSS include:

```
<link href="http://www.domain.com/css/mainstyle.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
```

It uses the absolute path because there's a lot of SEO, subdirectories etc, so it's much easier to include it like this than by looking for relative paths.

If I open the page as http://www.domain.com/test.php it works fine, but if I open it as https://www.domain.com/test.php Chrome refuses to load the stylesheet!

It works in Firefox and Safari. I can understand IE being a 'special needs' browser, but why is Chrome doing this and how can I fix it?

Calling the CSS file with https://domain.com/css/mainstyle.css fixes the issue, but is it really necessary?

Comment: Is the issue on the style sheet only?

Comment: Asin the page isn't been styled or you are unable to access it?

Comment: have you tried `href="//www.domain.com/css/mainstyle.css"` ?

Comment: As in, the page isn't being styled. The issue is on the stylesheet only, the images are loaded fine, as is the Javascript.

Comment: The reason this is blocked is that it's a security hole (called a "Mixed Content" vulnerability.) Most browsers will block insecure resources to keep a HTTPS page secure. See e.g. http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ie/archive/2011/06/23/internet-explorer-9-security-part-4-protecting-consumers-from-malicious-mixed-content.aspx

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Maybe try `Protocol Relative URLs` :

> < link href="//www.domain.com/css/mainstyle.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" >

[The Protocol-relative URL - Paul Irish](http://www.paulirish.com/2010/the-protocol-relative-url/)

Hope it can help!

Answer (score 0):

You need to allow .css, .js, .png, .jpg, .bmp, .gif, .eof, .ttf, .svg files in .htaccess file for https page.

For security purpose Chrome not allowed these files on these pages.
BUT Firefox allowed.