# CSS not working on http but working for www

Tags: html, css, subdomain

I recently hosted a site. But when I enter my site address as for example **www.example.com** then my css style sheet are working fine.but when I enter the site as **http://example.com** then css is not working only the html body is showing.What is the problem behind this?

Comment: Provide some code or link.

Comment: can u show your website link

Comment: @M0GLI  try this link....this might help you...](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17684229/css-doesnt-work-on-https-pages-in-chrome-and-ie)

Comment: http://www.telecomtechnology-tools.com/

Comment: plz add you < link href="" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" > in question

Answer (score 0):

The issue may be because of the redirection of domains. The http://www.example.com and http://example.com are two completely different urls. You have to redirect either one to other. Also, check other urls of your site whether the redirections are working properly or not.

Comment: my website link is: www.telecomtechnology-tools.com. How to redirect one to other?

Comment: it is working in my PC. Try clearing the cache. The easiest way to clear it is adding ? sign and some random text. eg: www.telecomtechnology-tools.com/?dfaefea

Answer (score 0):

try using Protocol Relative URLs, these are used for linking to a website that offers both HTTP and HTTPS.
and also clear your cache.

```
< link href="//www.example.com/css/your-style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" >
```

go through this link for more info
http://www.paulirish.com/2010/the-protocol-relative-url/

Hope this work!